# Как сохранять случайно выпавшее число в настольной игре?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity3d

Создаю настольную игру.

Сделал код для случайного выпадения кубика и числа, но не могу придумать, **как сохранить это случайное число**, которое я использую для начала движения фишки.

```
public Sprite[] diceSide;
    public int dropNumber;
    public Image diceImage;
    public GameObject insideDice;

      IEnumerator DropNumber()
    {
        dropNumber = Random.Range(1, 7);
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            diceImage.sprite = diceSide[Random.Range(0, diceSide.Length)];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }
        diceImage.sprite = diceSide[dropNumber - 1];

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);

        insideDice.SetActive(false);
        outsideDice.SetActive(true);
    }
```

Comment: Куда вы хотите сохранить число? Приведите пожалуйста хоть немного кода.

Comment: `int peremennaya = 0;`... Сохранил!

Comment: @МаксимФисман он, наверное, просто хочет сохранить его в переменную и достучаться до неё из другого скрипта

Comment: @KuzCode да сохранить выпавшее число чтобы потом фишка могла пойти по клетка с нумерацией выпало число 5 фишка пошла на 5 ячейку потом выпадает 2, и фишка идет на 7 ячейку, вот это не могу понять как реализовать

Comment: @МаксимФисман я хочу сохранять эти числа для того чтобы потом их использовать при движение фишки выпало число 5 фишка пошла на 5 ячейку потом выпадает 2, и фишка идет на 7 ячейку, вот это не могу понять как реализовать

Comment: @1zymryd сохраните число в публичную переменную в скрипте, где вы его генерируете и передайте скрипт с генератором в скрипт к фишке. Если до сих пор не поняли - тогда прикрепите код

Comment: @KuzCode 
public Sprite[] diceSide;
    public int dropNumber;
    public Image diceImage;
    public GameObject insideDice;

 IEnumerator DropNumber()
    {
        dropNumber = Random.Range(1, 7);
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            diceImage.sprite = diceSide[Random.Range(0, diceSide.Length)];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }
        diceImage.sprite = diceSide[dropNumber - 1];

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
}

Comment: @1zymryd напишите код каждого скрипта с подписью в вопросе, а не в комментариях. И что бы выделить код используйте символы ` по краям, тогда получится вот так: `код`

Comment: @KuzCode добавил

Comment: @1zymryd как вы бы в коде использовали рандомное число, если бы знали как передать? приведите пример кодом

Comment: @KuzCode я еще не знаю как это но в плане передавать это число на фишку которая будет становиться на точку с int id того числа что выпало при следующем броске добавлялось ну как я уже говорил выпало число 2 фишка пошла на точку с id 2 потом + новое выпавшее число и так далее пока сумма не станет больше 21, не представляю вообще как этом делать поэтому тут и сижу, буду очень благодарен если подскажите

Comment: @1zymryd у вашей фишки должен быть свой скрипт, например, с действием `ПоходитьВТочку(int точка)`. Тогда в том скрипте, что есть у вас, вы сможете получить скрипт, привязанный к фишке. Допустим он называется `ФишкаСкрипт`. Тогда вы можете получить его следующим образом:

`var insideDiceScript = insideDice.GetComponent<ФишкаСкрипт>();`. После этого передайте в функцию кубика своё число: 
`insideDiceScript.ПоходитьВТочку(dropNumber)`

Comment: @KuzCode хорошо, сейчас попробую и отпишу что получилось, спасибо

Comment: @KuzCode скинул в ответы что получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (target != 0)
        {
            fishka.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(fishka.transform.position, points[target - 1].position, navigationTime);
            if (target <= newPosition - 1)
            {
                if (System.Math.Round(fishka.transform.position.x, 3) == System.Math.Round(points[target - 1].position.x, 3) && System.Math.Round(fishka.transform.position.y, 3) == System.Math.Round(points[target - 1].position.y, 3))
                    target++;
                else if (fishka.transform.position == points[points.Length - 1].position)
                    Destroy(fishka);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если этот код вы считаете ответом к вашему вопросу, вам стоит принять его, нажав галочку. Однако чистый код без каких-либо слов обычно не считается хорошим ответом на ruSO на вопрос, даже свой, помните.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите сохранить число в виде самого настоящего сохранения, то используйте PlayerPrefs.
PlayerPrefs сохраняет переменные в отдельный файл, чтобы эту переменную потом можно было использовать даже при перезаходе в игру, или удалить эту переменную :Р

Если вы хотите просто сохранить число и получать его в другом скрипте, то просто используйте статичные (или статические, в общем public static) переменные.